# 3 results of MySQL data in each row using PHP and twitter bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to display MySQL data of 3 results in each row using PHP and twitter bootstrap like this below.

```
1  2  3

4  5  6

7  8  9
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: i don't have,i just want the example, of how to do it ?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service I'm afraid.

Comment: i just want to know how to implement this method of displaying 3 results in each row using php and twitter bootstrap, your answers are welcomed here and it will be more useful to many.

Comment: Show us your start, we'll get you the rest of the way.

Comment: put every result in seperate div with class='col-sm-4'. of course you need to have parent div with class='row'

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic can u give me a short and simple sample example code.

Comment: No we can't (or rather shouldn't) give you example code. You need to show some effort first and then we can help.

Comment: I agree with this guy who told you to show us what you did so far.. so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make php query to retrieve data.
2. Set counter variable to 0.
3. Loop through data (for example use foreach statement):

   - Check if you need to print start `.row` div
   - Print `.col-*-4` and print data from DB.
   - Check if you need to print end `.row` div
   - increase the counter

Now write the code ;)

Comment: Not a problem at all. But just a reminder if I may. Next time you ask a question try to elaborate what have you tried and what you want to achieve. People here don't like to be "abused" for code monkeys ;)

It's a learning site and we all expect from others to try and explain what did they try and where it went wrong. Learn to ask the right questions - that way you will get the right answers ;)

Happy coding!